# How do I make my code Repeat instead of ending in c++?

Tags: c++, repeat

The code tells you if it's a prime or not, I've Tried Everything I could find, like a 'do while' loop and others It just won't work my code is if anyone could help.

though it is probably me putting it in the wrong place so if anyone could put my code in the way to do it that would help alot.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    {
        int n, i, m = 0, flag = 0;
        cout << "(press 'x' to exit) Enter the Number to check if It's a prime Number or not: ";
        cin >> n;

        m = n / 2;
        for (i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                cout << "That's not a prime number." << endl;
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0)
            cout << "That's a prime number." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: please show what you tried. A while or do-while should do the job, but we cannot know what didnt work when you dont show us

Comment: I did I said "Like a "do while loop" and others"

Comment: Suggestion: instead of "Press x to exit", use "Enter 0 to exit". After all, nobody cares about testing the primality of 0. And it will make things easier.

Comment: but you didnt show the code. We want to help you with your specific detail that you have an issue with and that is easiest when you show the code that doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a while(true) around everything. I see you already got the {} for that:

```
int main()
{
    while (true) {
        int n, i, m = 0, flag = 0;
```

If you do it this way it will endlessly continue asking. Ctrl+C will end the program.

If you want to have the press x to exit working, something like this would work:

```
int main()
{
    while (true) {
        string s;
        int n, i, m = 0, flag = 0;
        cout << "(press 'x' to exit) Enter the Number to check if It's a prime Number or not: ";
        cin >> s;

        if (s == "x")
            break;

        n = atoi( s.c_str() );

        m = n / 2;
```

Comment: Thank you, This did work however it doesn't show the typed number after the first input any way to fix that?
Edit: Actually after implementing that to make x exit it fixed it Thank you!

Comment: I am on linux and did not have that problem: https://snipboard.io/VKJuxU.jpg

Comment: It's all good now adding x to exit fixed it thank you!