# while repeat not stop after i input one time

Tags: c++, while-loop

how do i get my program to repeat non stop? i want it to keep asking me to input the same information for multiple students. and not stop after i input once.
can someone help please? i really appreciate all the help thank you guys.

```
enter code here

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int midterm=0;
    int final=0;

    cout << "please enter midterm grade: ";
    cin >> midterm;
    while (midterm < 0 || midterm > 200)
    {
        cout << "Please enter valid amount must be 0 or greater or 200 or less. please enter grade: ";
        cin >> midterm;
    }
    cout << "please enter final grade: ";
    cin >> final;
    while (final < 0 || final > 200)
    {
        cout << "Please enter valid amount must be 0 or greater or 200 or less. Please enter grade";
        cin >> final;
    }

    int total;
    total = final + midterm;

    if (total > 360 && total <= 400)
    {
        cout << "your letter grade is A";
    }
    else if (total > 320 && total <= 360)
    {
        cout << "your letter grade is B";
    }
    else if (total > 280 && total <= 320)
    {
        cout << "your letter grade is C";
    }
    else if (total > 240 && total <= 280)
    {
        cout << "your letter grade is D";
    }
    else if (total <= 240)
    {
        cout << "your letter is F";
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a loop around all the code you already have?

Comment: It also becomes much easier if you pull out all the code inside the `main` function, and put it into a separate function that you call. Adding a loop around that single call might be easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your whole code in a loop that never stops.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while(true) {
        int midterm=0;
        int final=0;
    
        cout << "please enter midterm grade: ";
        cin >> midterm;
        while (midterm < 0 || midterm > 200)
        {
            cout << "Please enter valid amount must be 0 or greater or 200 or less. please enter grade: ";
            cin >> midterm;
        }
        cout << "please enter final grade: ";
        cin >> final;
        while (final < 0 || final > 200)
        {
            cout << "Please enter valid amount must be 0 or greater or 200 or less. Please enter grade";
            cin >> final;
        }
    
        int total;
        total = final + midterm;
    
        if (total > 360 && total <= 400)
        {
            cout << "your letter grade is A";
        }
        else if (total > 320 && total <= 360)
        {
            cout << "your letter grade is B";
        }
        else if (total > 280 && total <= 320)
        {
            cout << "your letter grade is C";
        }
        else if (total > 240 && total <= 280)
        {
            cout << "your letter grade is D";
        }
        else if (total <= 240)
        {
            cout << "your letter is F";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

This question has been asked and answered before as well: [How do I make my code Repeat instead of ending in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69071570/how-do-i-make-my-code-repeat-instead-of-ending-in-c/69071605#69071605)

Comment: Note that the "_Put your whole code in a loop that never stops_" suggestion is not a good idea because infinite loops makes the program have undefined behavior.

Comment: his suggestion worked though so what is the point of your comment?

Comment: @ColtonGil The appearance that it works is one possible outcome of having a program with undefined behavior but one should not rely on it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think you have a great opportunity here to show us how to create something that does what was requested while also not having undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Veda The only thing required is that there's a way for the program to get out of the loop. `if(!(cin >> midterm)) break;` would be enough in this case.